# How to prove two functions cannot be solutions of a same ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question:

Consider here the two functions $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $f(t=-t^2 +t + 1$ and $g(t)= cos(t)+sin(t)$. Show that $f, g$ are not solutions of a same ODE on $\mathbb R$ of the form $(E): y' = F(t,y)$, with $F:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ a function that is continuous and such that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ exists and is continuous.

My attempt:

I know this statement must be true by Picard-Lindelöf Theorem. Since with initial condition $y(0) = 1$. This IVP must have one unique solution. By I don't really know how to wirte a formal proof.

Comment: Your reasoning seems formally sound to me. For all such ODEs, uniqueness by Picard-Lindelöf implies if both $f$ and $g$ are solutions $f = g$ over all of $\mathbb{R}$, which is clearly false, hence, by contradiction, $f$ and $g$ are not both solutions.

Comment: The intro of this wiki could give you ideas: [Singular solution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_solution)